# Obtaining duration for Youtube activities through Youtube-data api

Tags: duration, youtube-data-api

I am using the following api call to obtain activities.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=contentDetails%2Csnippet&
     home=true&maxResults=15&&fields=items&key=<my key>access_token=<my token>
```

It works fine, except that it does not display the duration in the response. I have tried adding "duration" in the fields parameter, but it doesn't work.

What is the way to obtain the duration in a single request?